# Ansible. Call for function for each changes

Tags: function, automation, ansible, yaml

I have a task which must check the database list of stores in the .ini file, and if it is not exist - create it from the file.

Currently I have this task which check the database present:

```
- name: Check DB (if necessary)
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state=present
  register: db_created
  with_ini:
    - databases[1-100]
    - section: sites
    - file: "lookup.ini"
    - re: true
```

But it is just check the present of db and stay rise event "db_created".

And I need to create the new database with task like this:

```
- name: Import DB (if it was created)
  mysql_db:
    name=my_database
    state=import
    target=/tmp/database.sql
  when: db_created.changed
```

But with this task it will be call once, not the for all databases which I need to create. And I need to know exactly which database need to be created.

Can you help, how to call second one with correct name of database, and for all database if there more then one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad syntax apart, your first task does not just check, but ensures that db is present (create new db if it is not found).

In your `db_created` result you have per item `changed` status.
Something like this should do the job:

```
- name: Check DB (if necessary)
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  register: db_created
  with_ini:
    - databases[1-100]
    - section: sites
    - file: "lookup.ini"
    - re: true

- name: Import DB (if it was created)
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ item.item }}"
    state: import
    target: /tmp/database.sql
  when: item is changed
  with_items: "{{ db_created.results }}"
```

Or event like this (to iterate only over changed items):

```
- name: Import DB (if it was created)
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ item.item }}"
    state: import
    target: /tmp/database.sql
  with_items: "{{ db_created.results | select('changed') | list }}"
```

Note: about your syntax – forget `=`, always use `:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.